# sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen on Android

Tags: android, security

In an app I try to generate a keystore. Sadly ive to use for compatibility reasons with already existing desktop clients the x509 certificate.

During keystore generation the app crashes with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen
E/AndroidRuntime(  338):    at ppa.utils.ssl.MiscSSLTools.createKeystore(MiscSSLTools.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(  338):    at it.sec.RegisterActiviy.continueReg(RegisterActiviy.java:129)
E/AndroidRuntime(  338):    at it.sec.RegisterActiviy.btnFinishRegClicked(RegisterActiviy.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime(  338):    ... 28 more
```

I think in the Android implementation of Java this class is missing and so it cannot be found. 
Does anybody got an idea how i could it get working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned class CertAndKeyGen seems to contain only some utility functions that can be easily implemented yourself in your application.

Just take a look onto the source code:

http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/security/x509/CertAndKeyGen.java.html